# How to configure Azure web app to host Nextjs app

Tags: azure, next.js

I'm trying to host a simple Nextjs application on Azure WebApp, i have tried to follow several online tutorials to configure it but none managed to help me.

I'm using the SSR configuration of the Nextjs and have only created two components to test it on the Azure hosting.

Right now i'm stuck at the server configuration for Node, i have tried place a web.config file that i saw on an example but it seems that my request isn't event reaching the application server.

This is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <webSocket enabled="false" />
        <handlers>
            <add name="iisnode" path="app/server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
        </handlers>

        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="API">
                    <match url="^api(.*)$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{SCRIPT_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{SCRIPT_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="api/index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>

                <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^app/server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
                </rule>

                <rule name="StaticContent">
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
                </rule>

                <rule name="DynamicContent">
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="app/server.js"/>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>

        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <hiddenSegments>
                    <remove segment="bin"/>
                </hiddenSegments>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>

        <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This is my server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')
const nextConfig = require('../next.config')

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({
    dev: dev,
    dir: './app',
    conf: nextConfig
})
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
    const server = express()

    server.get('/home', (req, res) => {
        return app.render(req, res, '/home', req.query)
    })

    server.get('*', (req, res) => {
        return handle(req, res)
    })

    server.listen(port, err => {
        if (err) throw err
            console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`)
    })
})
```

Comment: did you ever get this working?

Comment: No, we decided to publish on Vercel and gave up on the manual configuration.

Comment: probably the smarter choice

Comment: It is way easier and removes a LOT of headache, we also tried to work on Azure WebApp, we had small success but the pipeline for release was problematic.